# How set up database for my payment gateway project?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stripe-payments

project Scenario:

### Video and audio call service which has 4 prices

Database:

### company_Register table which accepts email, company name, and other following details. column ID is auto-generated which becomes the foreign key for the other two tables >Payment and >Subscribers.

The payment table collects all the details related to payment like subscription ID, Payment method ID, Stripe Customer ID, and Plan customer opted to, along with this company ID is also stored. whereas subscribers table stores company Name, Plan, Plan to start at (DATE), Plan to end at(DATE), and company ID.

### both tables have ID and company ID, ID is auto-generated whereas company ID is manually fed.

**Is this the right approach?**
**working on hibernate..very new to hibernate**
**unable to figure out the relations**

Comment: It sounds wrong to me that payment would store plan, but hey, it's your schema.

Comment: any suggestion as to how to set up the schema? - @Strawberry